# Unable to unset session variables on FB.logout

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm unable to to unset the PHP session variables on clicking the logout option. I'm confused on how to do this. However the action does log me out of FB. Can someone please help me?

HTML Code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Logout()">Logout</a>
```

JS Code:

```
function Logout()
{
   FB.logout(function(response) {
     console.log(response);     
   });
}
```

After reading a comment I have modified the code in the following way. Please do suggest if its the right way to do.

```
function Logout()
{
FB.logout(function(response) {
    confirm("You have successfully logged out from FB");
    window.location.href = '/logout.php';
    //window.location.reload();
    console.log(response);      
});
}
```

Code in logout.php

```
session_start();

unset($_SESSION['user_full_name']);
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
session_destroy();
header("Location: main.php");
```

Comment: is any of that code sending anything to your server to tell it you're logging out?

Comment: @MarcB thanks a lot for ur reply. No this is all the code related to this.

Comment: check session_write_close ()  AND session_regenerate_id ([ bool $delete_old_session = false ] )